# Lubuntu: Filesystem randomly gets remounted as read-only; requires fsck

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, lubuntu, ssd

I recently replaced Windows 10 with Lubuntu on my Lenovo ideapad. I wasn't having hard disk problems until now. This is an SSD by the way.

I use Firefox. I close it, then close the lid on the machine and put it away.

When I bring it back up, Firefox won't start because of .parentlock shenanigans.

Can't delete .parentlock because it's a read-only file system.

Check /proc/mounts, sure enough it's mounted ro. Remounting rw errors out, saying the file system is write-protected.

Reboot dumps me into initramfs. fsck finds errors. When I fix them and boot up, the file system is now properly mounted rw.

This is a recurring problem that happens only sometimes, maybe once every three. It's unpredictable as far as I can tell. Help please?

Comment: If errors are detected on a *fs* (file-system), a RW (read-write) *fs* is flipped to RO (read-only) to prevent data-loss, allowing you to `fsck` (file-system check) and correct the issues.  If it keeps occurring, it;'s a huge sign something is wrong which needs to be investigated.  I'd explore your system logs (`dmesg` usually, if the system was re-booted `journalctl`) and read the messages BEFORE the flip from RW to RO looking for clues as to the real issue. It maybe signs of hardware issues (RAM, PSU etc) unless there is a pattern.. but it's a sign of issue & *fs* flipping RO is the symptom

Comment: You provide no specifics as to what release of Lubuntu, not even which Lubuntu desktop you're using (legacy with LXDE or modern with LXQt). If you're using a LTS release, the software stack you're using is also of interest (*no details provided*) as issues can occur because of *kernel modules* (ie. *drivers*) and a fix maybe switching from whatever stack you're using to the alternate stack... but you provided no such details so I can only speak generally here as you gave no specifics.